# Can state in Proximal Policy Optimization contain history?

Tags: machine-learning, state, reinforcement-learning

For example can the State at timestep t actually be made of the state at t and t-1.

```
S_t = [s_t, s_t-1]
```

i.e. Does Proximal Policy Optimization already incorporate the state history, or can it be implicit in the State (or neither).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate your observations. This is very common to do it RL. Usually in atari domain the last four frames are joined into a single observation. This makes it possible for the agent to understand change in the environment.

a basic PPO algorithm does not by default implicitly keep track of state history. You could make this possible though by adding a recurrent layer.

Comment: When you say "the last for frames are joined into a single observation" do you mean that the state holds all four frames separately? In that case the state is responsible for holding onto (recent) history, and maybe you can get away without adding a recurrent layer?

Comment: you would be responsible for handling joining the last frames to a single frame. So you would manage the state/observation to look something like a FIFO queue. In some cases you can get away with no recurrent layer. The draw back of this is your network is limited to only using the concatenated k frames. While with an LSTM layer your model could selectively choose the features which are most important.